# TypeError: FigureBase.gca() got an unexpected keyword argument 'projection'

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
axes1 = fig.gca(projection = '3d')

1 axes1 = fig.add_axes(Axes3D(fig))
2 axes1 = fig.gca(projection=Axes3D.name)
3 axes1 = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
```

These are all the solutions i found during google, the first is the origional type of code, but was unusable after matplotlib 3.4
but the other 3 solution works differently with the first one

it's what I expected:

[image: it's what i expected]

it's the 1th:

[image: it's the 1th]

Answer (score 25):

This error happens due to Matplotlib update.

You can use

```
axes1 = fig.add_subplot(projection = '3d')
```

instead of

```
axes1 = fig.gca(projection = '3d')
```

Reference:
[Plot 2D data on 3D plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/2dcollections3d.html)